# How to hide disabled option from configurable product options

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

How to hide configurable product options values which are disabled in drop-down or in swatches.
As in the image red marked are disabled and not selectable.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can simply hide usging css or jQuery if they have disabled.

```
select option:disabled {
    display:none;
}
```

or

```
select option[disabled="disabled"]
{ 
    display:none;
}
```

using jquery

```
$(function() {       
      $('option[disabled="disabled"]').hide(); //then hide them                
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I know we can do it on the front end, but I am finding to hide it through the backend so that it can't be fetched on the front end.

Answer (score 0):

> **Please update your store configuration like the below and run reindex command.**

[image]

Comment: it is already set to no of out of stock products options still not working

Comment: It's Means Your product is disabled in admin?

Comment: Please check this issue : https://github.com/magento/inventory/issues/3296

Comment: All child products are enabled and in stock, but there is no one configurable attribute I am using, there are multiple attributes and some options are disabled and same options becomes enabled when i choose different option from other attribute.

Comment: Can you explain more about it? What do you want to achieve?